# Calling a session variable in a class object in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

How can I access the values stored in a session object with a class in asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use HttpContext for this:

```
string sessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionKey"] as string;
```

Just make sure your class imports the System.Web namespace, and this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub EnterInfoButton_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
    Session("FirstName") = Server.HtmlEncode(FirstNameTextBox.Text)
    Session("LastName") = Server.HtmlEncode(LastNameTextBox.Text)
    Session("Address") = Server.HtmlEncode(AddressTextBox.Text)
    Session("City") = Server.HtmlEncode(CityTextBox.Text)
    Session("StateOrProvince") = Server.HtmlEncode(StateOrProvinceTextBox.Text)
    Session("ZipCode") = Server.HtmlEncode(ZipCodeTextBox.Text)
    Session("Country") = Server.HtmlEncode(CountryTextBox.Text)

    EnterUserInfoPanel.Visible = False
    UserInfoPanel.Visible = True

    SetLabels()
  End Sub
```

Comment: @James Johnson, Within a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page it will.

Answer (score 0):

Have your class constructor take in a `HttpContext.Current` object parameter.  From that object, access the session property.